# Excel VBA incompatibility kernel32 calls

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

I have the below code in VBA which works perfectly fine in Excel 2003. 
Migrating the template to Excel 2007, doesn't work.

```
Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Long, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function WritePrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As Any, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Exit Sub


Dim WorksheetName As String
Dim WorksheetCell As String
Dim Section As String
Dim kKey As String
Dim lLine As Long
Dim InvoiceNumber As Long
Dim InvoiceNumberCell As Object
Dim TemplateName As String
Dim IniFileName As String
Dim Dummy As Variant

    TemplateName = "MyInvoicesTemplate.xlt"
    WorksheetName = "Invoice"
    WorksheetCell = "H2"
    Section = "Invoice"
    kKey = "Number"
    IniFileName = "C:\Windows\Temp\InvoiceNumber.txt"

    Set InvoiceNumberCell = Worksheets(WorksheetName).Range(WorksheetCell)
    If UCase(ActiveWorkbook.Name) = UCase(TemplateName) Then GoTo Finito
    Dummy = GetString(Section, kKey, IniFileName)
    If Left(Dummy, 1) = Chr$(0) Then
        InvoiceNumber = 1
    Else
        InvoiceNumber = CLng(Dummy) + 1
    End If
    WritePrivateProfileString Section, kKey, CStr(InvoiceNumber), IniFileName
    InvoiceNumberCell.Value = InvoiceNumber
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.CodeName).CodeModule
        lLine = .ProcBodyLine("Workbook_Open", vbext_pk_Proc)
        .InsertLines lLine + 1, "Exit Sub"
    End With
Finito:
Set InvoiceNumberCell = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetString(Section As String, Key As String, File As String) As String
    Dim KeyValue As String
    Dim Characters As Long
    KeyValue = String(255, 0)
    Characters = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", KeyValue, 255, File)
    If Characters > 1 Then
        KeyValue = Left(KeyValue, Characters)
    End If
    GetString = KeyValue
End Function
```

Any ideas why is this happening? 
I tried saving the template in different formats but no luck !

Thanks.
MK

Comment: Dick Kusleika link will definitely help you out. Also, Why do you have "Exit Sub" right at the begining in Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using 64 bit Office, the APIs have changed.  See

http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp

Comment: +1 Though the user has not mentioned 64 bit but the error message gives it all away :)

Answer (score 0):

API has changed.

IF VBA7, declare `ptrSafe` and `LongPtr`, etc.